# Recurrence series with matrix for $a_n=a_{n-1}-2a_{n-2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, recurrence-relations

> $a_0=0$, $a_1=1$, $a_n=a_{n-1} - 2a_{n-2}$ for $n\ge2$. Find a closed form for $a_n$.

So if I compute $a_2=1-0=1$, $a_3=1-2=-1$:
$$\begin{bmatrix} a_n\\a_{n-1} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a_{n-1} \\ a_{n-2}\end{bmatrix}$$
I think this matrix is true for $n\ge2$. But the idea is to find a matrix that satisfy $n\ge1$?

I can see that $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\0\end{bmatrix}$ is base case? And if they ask to find general term of $a_n$, I should find expression that satisfy the recurrence or the base case?

I suppose that $\begin{bmatrix} a_n\\a_{n-1} \end{bmatrix}  $ = $x_n$
and $\begin{bmatrix} a_{n-1} \\ a_{n-2}\end{bmatrix}=x_{n-1}$

$$x_{n}=Ax_{n-1}$$
$$x_{n-1}=A^{-1}x_n$$
clearly do not satisfy the equation, and what is the purpose of finding a matrix for this problem?

The right pattern is $x_n=A^{n-1}x_1$, I was confused why it has always to be $x_1$ and how can I find it? thanks

Comment: All your math is correct so far. Note that we have $x_1 = \left[\begin{smallmatrix} a_1 \\a_0\end{smallmatrix}\right] = \left[\begin{smallmatrix} 1 \\0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. The purpose of writing this as a matrix-vector product is that the powers of $A$ are relatively easy to compute using the full power of linear algebra.

Comment: @Arthur thankyou! but if n=1, it wont satisfy this equation right? $\begin{bmatrix} a_n\\a_{n-1} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a_{n-1} \\ a_{n-2}\end{bmatrix}$, and the purpose is to find equation that satisfy $n>=1$? how can I produce $x_n=A^{n-1}x_1$ from $x_{n}=Ax_{n-1}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So if I compute $a_2=1-0=1$, $a_3=1-2=-1$:
>   $$\begin{bmatrix} a_n\\a_{n-1} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a_{n-1} \\ a_{n-2}\end{bmatrix}$$

Good start.  Now continue that....

$$\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix} a_{n} \\ a_{n - 1} \end{bmatrix} &= 
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a_{n - 1} \\ a_{n - 2} \end{bmatrix}
\\ &= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a_{n - 2} \\ a_{n - 3} \end{bmatrix}
\\ &= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a_{n - 3} \\ a_{n - 4} \end{bmatrix}
\\ &= \dots
\end{align}$$

In summary $$\begin{bmatrix} a_{n + 1} \\ a_{n} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^n \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ a_0 \end{bmatrix}$$

> I think this matrix is true for $n\ge2$. But the idea is to find a matrix that satisfy $n\ge1$?

Well lets look at $n=1$:

$$\begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\a_{0} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a_{0} \\ a_{-1}\end{bmatrix}$$

So the $n = 1$ case is the equation $a_1 = a_{0} - 2a_{-1}$.  Since we have no information about $a_{-1}$, this is neither provable nor useful.  So $n \ge 2$ is fine.

> what is the purpose of finding a matrix for this problem?

Because it let's you reach $$\begin{bmatrix} a_{n + 1} \\ a_{n} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^n \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ a_0 \end{bmatrix}$$ after which you can use all kinds of nice matrix properties to say more things about the sequence.  For example, you could diagonalize $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ to get

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ \frac{2}{1 - \sqrt{-7}} & \frac{2}{1 + \sqrt{-7}} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1 - \sqrt{-7}}2 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1 + \sqrt{-7}}2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ \frac{2}{1 - \sqrt{-7}} & \frac{2}{1 + \sqrt{-7}} \end{bmatrix}^{-1}$$

so

$$\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix} a_{n + 1} \\ a_{n} \end{bmatrix} &= \left( \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ \frac{2}{1 - \sqrt{-7}} & \frac{2}{1 + \sqrt{-7}} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1 - \sqrt{-7}}2 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1 + \sqrt{-7}}2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ \frac{2}{1 - \sqrt{-7}} & \frac{2}{1 + \sqrt{-7}} \end{bmatrix}^{-1}\right)^n \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ a_0 \end{bmatrix} \\ &= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ \frac{2}{1 - \sqrt{-7}} & \frac{2}{1 + \sqrt{-7}} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1 - \sqrt{-7}}2 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1 + \sqrt{-7}}2 \end{bmatrix}^n \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ \frac{2}{1 - \sqrt{-7}} & \frac{2}{1 + \sqrt{-7}} \end{bmatrix}^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ a_0 \end{bmatrix} 
\end{align}$$

Ugh, this sequence doesn't simplify into anything pretty because of all the complex numbers.  But it is a straightforward way of deriving a formula of the form $a_{n} = C_1 \phi^n + C_2 {\varphi}~^n$

Also matrices keep the problem only involving integers instead of complex numbers, so computation is so much nicer.

> The right pattern is $x_n=A^{n-1}x_1$, I was confused why it has always to be $x_1$ and how can I find it? thanks

It is a bit cleaner to do $x_{n+1} = A^n x_1$.  You use $x_1$ as the base case because $a_1$ and $a_0$ is what you were given in the statement of the problem.  You can use any convenient $x$ that you can calculate as the base case, but why not just use the one given to you?

Comment: thankyou so much!!! $a_{n} = C_1 \phi^n + C_2 {\varphi}~^n$, is the solution always in this form? $ \begin{bmatrix} a_{n} \\ a_{n-1} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^{n-1} \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ a_0 \end{bmatrix}$ , can I diagonalize this instead? if I use $x_n=A^{n-1}x_1$, it is like I change the start point to $n \ge 1$ ? so the answer will be the top of the matrix, after diagonalization.

Comment: No, the general form is $$a_n = \sum_{j} \phi_{j}{}^n \sum_{k} C_{j, k}  {n}^{k}$$  Lookup jordan normal forms to see how matrices can be diagonalized.  You diagonalize a matrix, not a formula, so applying diagonalization to the matrix in your $n-1$ form works fine too.  I don't know what you mean by change the start point.

Comment: ok thankyou so much for your help!!!!  @DanielV

Answer (score 1):

You don't need matrices to solve your equation. The matrix approach for second degree recurrences is useful for determining limits or asymptotics.

This kind of linear equations can be solved as linear differential equations. You need to find two linearly independent solutions to the equation, with this you can write the general solution and then find the coefficients from the initial values.

Try with a solution of the form $a_n:=r^n$ for some non zero constant $r$. Substitution gets

$$r^2-r+2=0,$$

This means that two possible values of $r$ are given by 
$$r_{\pm}:=\frac{1\pm i\sqrt{7}}{2},$$

I.e. two solutions to your equation are

$$a_n^+ = (r_+)^n, a_n^-=(r_-)^n.$$

General solution can be written as

$$a_n=\alpha a_n^+ + \beta a_n^-$$

for some complex values $ \alpha,\beta$ which you can determine from your initial values.

Comment: Not sure how you would logically derive the equation for the roots without using matrices though.  Sure you can go through the algorithm, but how will you know why it works?

Comment: It works as soon it provides two l.i. solutions (indeed the case). If it gives only one, there is a way of constructing a second solution from the first. The solution space is a vector space of dimension 2. Is it clearer?

Comment: @Tal-Botvinnik I try this one, and I got it and even I don't need to do diagonalization, etc. is this because you treat it like linear differential equation? because of the constant coefficient $x^2,x^1,x$ ? anyway, can I choose arbitrary $n$ for this, as long as I can still get the root of it ?  $ a_n:=r^n$. thankyou!!

Comment: I don't understand you comment fully, but yes, you can treat it like a linear differential equation. The underlying algebraic structure is the same (solutions form vector spaces of dimension 2). This method is more direct than the matrix approach, and the calculations are, in a way, equivalent. Note how the value $1+i\sqrt 7$ appears in the matrix solution too.

Comment: And yes, the given solution holds for arbitrary $n$

Comment: @Tal-Botvinnik ok, thankyou so much for the explanation!!!